# Link buttons in toolbar menu overflow gets opened in same window, sample code below

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Toolbar overflow example',
    launch: function() {
        var addedItems = [];
        Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
            renderTo: document.body,
            id: 'toolbarId',
            width: 500,
            overflowHandler: 'menu',

            items: [{
                text: 'link button 1',
                href: 'www.google.com',
                width:100,
            }, {
                text: ' button 1',
                 width:100,
            }, {
                text: ' button 2'
            }, {
                text: 'button 3 '
            }, {
                text: 'button 4'
            }, {
                text: 'link button 1',
                href: 'www.yahoo.com',//this link is opened in same window
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your link button like:

```
{
    href: 'http://google.com',
    text: 'Link Item 4',
    hrefTarget: '_blank'
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15ll)

Comment: We already have '_blank' for buttons, as default value for target.

Comment: I know, but atleast in sencha fiddle without `hrefTarget: '_blank'` `href` property doesnt work correctly.

Comment: This is because the menu does not inherit the `defaults` config from the toolbar. This is an Ext bug you should definitely report at Sencha forum.